Suppose $\dot x = Ax$ is the linearization $\dot y = f(y)$. Is it true that all equilibria of $\dot x = Ax$ are also equilibrium of $\dot y = f(y)$?
Suppose $\dot x = Ax$ is the linearization  $\dot y = f(y)$.
By linearization, I mean $A = \partial f/\partial y|_{y = \bar y}$ where $\bar y$ is an equilibrium of $\dot y = f(y)$.

(I) Then is it true that all equilibria of $\dot x = Ax$ are also
equilibrium of $\dot y = f(y)$? (I am not sure)

(II) Furthermore, are all the equilibria of $\dot y = f(y)$ also
equilibria of $\dot x = Ax$? (This one is probably false).


To show (I), I need to show $f(\text{ker}(A)) = 0$, but I'm not sure how to proceed.
(II) probably needs a counter-example of a nonlinear system with two isolated equilibria.

I) No. Consider, for example,
$$\tag{1}
\dot x= x^2+y^2,\quad \dot y= x^2-y^2.
$$
We have $A=0$, but (1) has only one equilibrium, $(0,0)$.
II) No. The system $\dot y= \sin y$ has infinitely many equilibrium points $y=\pi n$, $n\in\mathbb Z$, but the linearized at $0$ system $\dot x =x$ has only one equilibrium, $0$.
